# How to keep my particles from getting messed up once converted?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

If this were sphere shapes for something like marbles I wouldn't mind, but I'm trying to do some grass. It all looks good while not converted.

[image]

But then I convert it and ...

[image]

How to avoid this?

Thanks guys,

DPC

Comment: Can you define 'converted'? What are you converting it to?

Comment: I was missing making them all single objs before joining them. Got to make a note of that...

Comment: In the Modifiers stack, on the tab corresponding to the Particle sys, there is only one big horizontal button called "convert". Once you use it it'll create one independent mesh per particle. Which you can of course manipulate in many different ways to suit your needs. Without affecting your still controlled particles.